# How to split input value using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to split chain input value and want to add `<br/>` after every end of `,`

```
<input type="text" class="title" />
<a class="into"></a>
```

```
$('.title').on('keyup change', function() {
  $('.into').text($(this).val());
});
```

Output :
 `demo1,demo2,`
Want to output :
`demo1
 demo2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:-

```
$('.title').on('keyup change', function() {
   var p=$(this).val().split(',').join(',</br>');
  $('.into').html(p);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w5r6zwru/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `replace()`

```
$('.title').on('keyup change', function() {
    var p=$(this).val().replace(/,/g, ',<br>');
  $('.into').html(p);
});
```

***[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5r6zwru/2/)***